# How to modify Hide/Show button for class instead of ID

Tags: javascript, class

I have found this code for a hide/show ID effect. I am building with Elementor in WP.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">show / hide</button>
```

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById ("showprice");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

This works, but I would like to modify the code to hide/show a Class instead of ID - but changing it to the following doesn’t work. Any tips?

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("showprice");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a HTMLCollection, which is a collection of elements, not a single element

Comment: Fabulous! Now I am wondering if there is a tweak that will load the page with the class hidden by default?

Comment: Sure, but that's not what you asked

Comment: All good, surprisingly I worked it out by my baby self!

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a HTMLCollection. So it returns an array :)
You should probably do a loop to iterate over all the elements and then apply your logic:

```
function myFunction() {
  var elts = document.getElementsByClassName("showprice");
  elts.forEach((x) => {
     if (x.style.display === "none") {
       x.style.display = "block";
     } else {
       x.style.display = "none";
     }
  })
}
```

Comment: why are you (mis)using `.map` for this?

Comment: I don't get it, what's wrong with map ?

Comment: nothing, you CAN use a flathead screwdriver on a phillips head screw, but it's not the right tool :p

Comment: I see your point. I changed it to a forEach

Answer (score 0):

Using getElementsByClassName returns a collection of elements rather than a single element like getElementById.
So you need to loop through each element in the collection to apply the style changes

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">show / hide</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("showprice");
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].style.display === "none" || x[i].style.display === "") {
      x[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

- Looping through all elements with class name 'showprice'.
- We're checking its current display style and toggling it accordingly.
- If the elements style is 'none' or empty, we set it to 'block' to show it, else 'none' to hide it.

This should achieve the hide/show effect for elements with the class "showprice".

Answer (score -2):

You can also use querySelector or querySelectorAll to select a class or multiple class with same name and then loop through it with the forEach method as below:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.querySelectorAll(".showprice");
    x.forEach(elem=>{
        if (elem.style.display === "none") {
            elem.style.display = "block";
          } else {
            elem.style.display = "none";
          }
    })
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">show/hide</button>
<div class="showprice">hello</div>
<div class="showprice">hello</div>
<div class="showprice">hello</div>
<div class="showprice">hello</div>
```